# CrystalReport - How to display multiple strings after checking if it's null or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to check receipt number & receipt date is null or not and display on the report, If number or date is null then display " ".

**I tried this code:**

```
Local StringVar ReceiptNo :=IIF(IsNull({usp_GetInvoideByBillNo_IMPORT.Receipt_No}),"",{usp_GetInvoideByBillNo_IMPORT.Receipt_No});
Local StringVar ReceiptDate :=IIF(IsNull({usp_GetInvoideByBillNo_IMPORT.RECEIPT_DATE}), "", ToText({usp_GetInvoideByBillNo_IMPORT.RECEIPT_DATE},"dd/MM/yyyy"));
ReceiptNo + ReceiptDate
```

In one of my record receipt date is null and receipt number is not null then it should display receipt number, but it is not displaying receipt number. I checked the report after entering receipt date then it is displaying proper receipt number & date.
Please check the code and let me know in case of any mistakes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. As per IBM documentation, there's defect in CrystalReport because of which `IIF` and `IsNull` can't be used together.

`There is a defect in Crystal Reports 8.x and 10.x that prevents the above formula from working correctly. The 'IIF' and 'IsNull' commands cannot function together, and that includes attempting to use "Not" to modify the IsNull command; for example, IIF(Not IsNull ()).`https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21143931

Workaround is to use `If-Then-Else` syntax

`If IsNull({getValue.Sr_No}) Then "0" Else "In Progress"`